# CMake add_subdirectory() for SDL_image out of tree build

Tags: cmake, build, sdl

I cloned the [`SDL_image`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image) library and wish to build it using a simple `add_subdirectory(...)` command. My current directory structure is as follows.

```
├───lib
│   ├───sdl_image
|       ├─── ...
├───build
```

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` which is as follows.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(test)
add_subdirectory(lib/sdl_image)
```

Upon execution (For my environment, `cmake . -G "MinGW Makefiles"`), I get the following error.

```
CMake Error at lib/sdl_image/CMakeLists.txt:18 (message):
  Prevented in-tree built.  Please create a build directory outside of the
  SDL_image source code and call cmake from there
```

In an attempt to fix this, I modified my `CMakeLists.txt` `add_subdirectory(...)` command as follows. If I understand correctly, this should specify the output directory to `build/sdl_image`, outside of the `SDL_image` source code.

```
...
add_subdirectory(lib/sdl_image build/sdl_image)
```

However, I still get the same error. The line that is giving me the error under `lib/sdl_image/CMakeLists.txt` is as follows.

```
if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR ...)
endif()
```

I don't understand why this condition is getting triggered since I've specified the `source_dir` and `binary_dir` (parameters in `add_subdirectory(...)`) as very different paths. I also tried `add_subdirectory(lib/sdl_image ../../build/sdl_image)` in case it was treated as relative to the `source_dir`. This is still not working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about building in sources (calling cmake in your sources), not a path problem where to put sdl_image.

You probably call cmake from within your source directory which is considered a bad practice (same thing when using autotools, or any other build generator).

So you should have some kind of build tree like:

```
MyProjectWorkspace
|
\_ sources (tree in your case)
\_ build
```

and invoke cmake with `cmake ../sources` from within the build directory.

The reason is that when building in sources, you somehow "pollute" your sources. Very likely you will need to add some .gitignore (if using git) and take special care not to commit thing that are built.

Moreover, when generating code, the generated code will appear in the source tree leading to some confusions at some point (you edit the generated file and see it deleted later).

It is also handy: to completely clear a build, you only need to remove the content of the build directory (would be much harder within the sources)

Last but not least, this also ease the packager's job as usually, the use off source builds.

Comment: In the context here, I call cmake from MyProjectWorkspace. Also, doesn't this assume that my CMakeLists.txt is in the build directory? Also, CMake ignores ../build since this does nothing as you are currently in build/. (CMake: Ignoring extra path from command line: "../build")

Comment: what I call sources shoud be your 'tree' directory. The bottom line is that you should not call cmake from a directory that contains a CMakeLists.txt. You should invoke it from a specific (empty) build directory

Comment: Using the same structure from the original question, I call `cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"` from `build/`. From the original question, my `CMakeLists.txt` is located one directory behind `build/`. I still receive the same error. Also, `tree` is just the command I used to generate the structure. I'll remove it from the question.

Comment: did you clear the sources fro the previous cmake call you did (the cmake . -G "MinGW Makefiles") ?

Comment: I did not. I was invoking that previous Makefile from the previous invocation. Invoking cmake from build/ worked. Appreciate the help.